# How to expand one column in Pandas to many columns?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, bigdata

As the title, I have one column (series) in pandas, and each row of it is a list like `[0,1,2,3,4,5]`. Each list has 6 numbers. I want to change this column into 6 columns, for example, the `[0,1,2,3,4,5]` will become 6 columns, with `0` is the first column, `1` is the second, `2` is the third  and so on. How can I make it?

Answer (score 12):

Not as fast as @jezrael's solution.  But elegant :-)

`apply` with `pd.Series`

```
df.a.apply(pd.Series)

   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  0  1  2  3  4  5
1  0  1  2  3  4  5
```

or

```
df.a.apply(pd.Series, index=list('abcdef'))

   a  b  c  d  e  f
0  0  1  2  3  4  5
1  0  1  2  3  4  5
```

Comment: bigdata - it will be very slow ;)

Comment: @jezrael yes it will

Answer (score 7):

You can convert lists to `numpy array` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) and then use `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[[0,1,2,3,4,5],[0,1,2,3,4,5]]})
print (df)
                    a
0  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
1  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df['a'].values.tolist())
print (df1)
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  0  1  2  3  4  5
1  0  1  2  3  4  5
```

---

```
cols = list('abcdef')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df['a'].values.tolist(), columns=cols)
print (df1)
   a  b  c  d  e  f
0  0  1  2  3  4  5
1  0  1  2  3  4  5
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you are looking for a transpose operation.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5],columns='a')
# .T stands for transpose
print(df.T)
```

Comment: But I have 1000 rows, and I want to transfer each of all the rows  into 6 individual columns..

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

# create a sample DataFrame with a column containing comma-separated values
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['John,Doe', 'Jane,Smith', 'Bob,Jones']})

# split the values in the 'Name' column and create new columns for each element
df[['First Name', 'Last Name']] = df['Name'].str.split(',', expand=True)

# drop the original 'Name' column
df = df.drop('Name', axis=1)

# print the resulting DataFrame
print(df)
```