# converty numpy array of arrays to 2d array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a pandas series `features` that has the following values (`features.values`)

```
array([array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]),
       array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]), ...,
       array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]),
       array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0])], dtype=object)
```

Now I really want this to be recognized as matrix, but if I do

```
>>> features.values.shape
(10000,)
```

rather than `(10000, 3000)` which is what I would expect.

How can I get this to be recognized as 2d rather than a 1d array with arrays as values. Also why does it not automatically detect it as a 2d array?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42920363/how-to-expand-one-column-in-pandas-to-many-columns

Comment: Try `np.stack(features)`.  It treats the array as a list of arrays, and concatenates them on a new axis.  `np.vstack(features)` would also work in this case.  That's assuming that all internal arrays have the same shape.

Comment: @anishtain4, your link is for a `pandas` dataframe, not a numpy array.

Comment: @hpaulj "I have a pandas series"

Comment: @hpaulj `np.stack` worked great. Just really dont understand why `features.values` doesn't return it as such, or why numpy doesnt recognize it as a 2d array. Thank you!

Comment: The object dtype is a barrier.  The outer array has pointers to arrays else where in memory. Its structure is different from that of a 2d array.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In response your comment question, let's compare 2 ways of creating an array

First make an array from a list of arrays (all same length):

```
In [302]: arr = np.array([np.arange(3), np.arange(1,4), np.arange(10,13)])
In [303]: arr
Out[303]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 1,  2,  3],
       [10, 11, 12]])
```

The result is a 2d array of numbers.

If instead we make an object dtype array, and fill it with arrays:

```
In [304]: arr = np.empty(3,object)
In [305]: arr[:] = [np.arange(3), np.arange(1,4), np.arange(10,13)]
In [306]: arr
Out[306]: 
array([array([0, 1, 2]), array([1, 2, 3]), array([10, 11, 12])],
      dtype=object)
```

Notice that this display is like yours.  This is, by design a 1d array.  Like a list it contains pointers to arrays elsewhere in memory.  Notice that it requires an extra construction step.  The default behavior of `np.array` is to create a multidimensional array where it can.

It takes extra effort to get around that.  Likewise it takes some extra effort to undo that - to create the 2d numeric array.

Simply calling `np.array` on it does not change the structure.

```
In [307]: np.array(arr)
Out[307]: 
array([array([0, 1, 2]), array([1, 2, 3]), array([10, 11, 12])],
      dtype=object)
```

`stack` does change it to 2d.  `stack` treats it as a list of arrays, which it joins on a new axis.

```
In [308]: np.stack(arr)
Out[308]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 1,  2,  3],
       [10, 11, 12]])
```

Answer (score 13):

Shortening @hpauli answer:

```
your_2d_arry = np.stack(arr_of_arr_object)
```