# Reshape an array using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array with the next distribution

```
array -> shape(878,)
```

one element inside array

```
shape(313,313,3)
```

What I have to do to get the next result?

```
shape(878,313,313,3)
```

thanks

Comment: So elements of the array are arrays? Can you provide [mcve]?

Comment: If your array elements are 3D arrays _of the same size_, then it is automatically a 4D array.

Comment: What's the dtype?  Object?  Then you have an array of arrays.  If so, then this other recent question is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50971123/converty-numpy-array-of-arrays-to-2d-array

Comment: Is the dtype of your array `object`?  There are a few ways you could have constructed a 1-D array of length 878 containing arrays, but typically they'd involve a mistake of sizing.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that datatypes are not an issue, you should be able to stack them using

```
np.stack(yourArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it an array or a dictionary. But even if you want to change the size , you could directly use np.reshape() for this operation but if you want ot change it in some different way, here is a way:

```
x = np.zeros((array.size,313,313,3)) # you could replace the numbers with shape of elements

for i in range(array.size):

    x[i] = a[i]
```

Comment: This will be less efficient than letting numpy handle the work for you. Check my answer.

Comment: Why do `x = np.array([])` and then reassign to x with `x = np.zeros((array.size,313,313,3))`? :p

Comment: Another thing, setting x and then resetting it is a waste.

Comment: Beat me to it @JayCalamari

Comment: Yeah, I know that that's why I gave it as an alternate solution if he wanted to see how that actually happens or yeah np.vstack() might directly work for him. But thanks for noticing.

Comment: Ooh thanks @JayCalamari I copied a wrong part of code to it I did not notice.