# can not convert pandas numpy column into tensors

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, numpy-ndarray, tf.keras

I am trying to convert one of my columns into tensor and it gives me an error. But if I try to convert the array by itself i wont have a problem.

for example this works:

```
dummy_array = [np.array([0.1, 0.2]), np.array([0.3, 0.4]), np.array([0.5, 0.6]), np.array([0.7, 0.8]), np.array([0.9, 0.11])]
```

tf.convert_to_tensor((dummy_array))

But this does not:

```
sample_df = pd.DataFrame()
sample_df['id'] = [1,2,3,4,5]
sample_df['x'] = dummy_array
sample_df['y'] = np.random.randint(0,2,size=5)
sample_df['x'] = sample_df['x'].apply(lambda x: x.astype('float32'))
tf.convert_to_tensor(sample_df['x'])
```

the error i get is:

```
 Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).
```

i want to keep it in dataframe so i can suffle and do train, val, test splits

Comment: Does this answer your question? [converty numpy array of arrays to 2d array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50971123/converty-numpy-array-of-arrays-to-2d-array)

Answer (score 0):

Before converting Pandas dataframe to Tensor convert Dataframe column to list.

Find the working example below.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
sample_df = pd.DataFrame()
sample_df['id'] = [1,2,3,4,5]
dummy_array = [np.array([0.1, 0.2]), np.array([0.3, 0.4]), np.array([0.5, 0.6]), np.array([0.7, 0.8]), np.array([0.9, 0.11])]
sample_df['x'] = dummy_array
sample_df['y'] = np.random.randint(0,2,size=5)
sample_df['x'] = sample_df['x'].apply(lambda x: x.astype('float32'))
tf.convert_to_tensor(sample_df['x'].to_list())
```

Output

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(5, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0.1 , 0.2 ],
       [0.3 , 0.4 ],
       [0.5 , 0.6 ],
       [0.7 , 0.8 ],
       [0.9 , 0.11]], dtype=float32)>
```